# Topics section missing from Azure Service Bus namespace on Standard Pricing Tier

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azureportal

I've got 2 Service Bus namespaces, both on the Standard Tier.

The older of the two only shows the Queues option and the option to create a Topic is disabled, however there are existing Topics in the namespace and these all work correctly.
[image]

The newer one which was created today has Topics enabled.

Both of them show as Standard Tier in the Portal:

Namespace missing Topics:

[image]

Namespace with Topics:

[image]

If I try to change the older one to Basic, it fails due to the existing Topics.
My theory is that this is a bug in the Portal and, while the underlying Azure infrastructure and the Scaling section of the portal know that this is a Standard Tier, that some part of it is not recognizing this, thus the missing Topics.

It should also be noted that if I generate an Automation Script, it wants to create this namespace as a Basic SKU but the other one as a Standard. It may be that at some point in the past (many years ago), this was a Basic tier.

So my question is, is there anything else I can check on the older namespace that may be incorrect that I can resolve or is this a bug in the Portal?

Comment: When it comes to managing Azure Service Bus namespaces with Azure Portal, it's far from optimal. I would recommend to look at tool such as [Serverless360](https://www.serverless360.com/), [Queue Explorer](https://www.cogin.com/mq/), or [ServiceBus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/milestones). As for your question, I suspect the namespace either too old to be converted or there are some limitations to the portal itself. Best to ping MSFT support to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the links Sean, will take a look at them. I pinged Support on Twitter and they told me to post it here so they could get someone to take a look.

Answer (score 7):

I just came into the same issue, I got a Service Bus resource from our Dev Ops team and it turned out that the topic feature is missing. The reason is that the pricing tier was basic.
[image]